# which one is the correct derivative w.r.t time?

Tags: matrix-calculus

We want to take time derivative of

$x^TPx$

and we know $\dot{x}=Ax,~~P^T=P$.

Which one is wrong and why?

1- $d(x^TPx)/dt=\nabla (x^TPx).\dot{x}=2x^TP\dot{x}=2x^TPAx.$

2- $d(x^TPx)/dt=\dot{x}^TPx+x^TP\dot{x}=x^TA^TPx+x^TPAx$

Comment: You should exclude a time-dependent $P$

Answer (score 1):

The second expression is correct, and can be recast into a form that looks more like the first, i.e. 
$\,\,2\,x^TA^TPx $

You just got your matrix term transposed somehow.

To prevent myself from making transposition mistakes, I usually employ a derivation in terms of the Frobenius product, like so
$$\eqalign{
  f &= x^TPx \cr
    &= P:xx^T \cr\cr
 df &= P:2\,{\rm sym}(dx\,x^T) \cr
   &= 2\,{\rm sym}(P):dx\,x^T \cr
   &= 2\,Px:dx \cr
   &= 2\,Px:Ax\,dt \cr\cr
 \frac{df}{dt}  &= 2\,Px:Ax \cr
   &= 2\,A^TP:xx^T \cr
   &= 2\,x^TA^TPx \cr
}$$

where  $\,{\rm sym}(M) \equiv \frac{1}{2}(M+M^T)\,$ and $\,A\!:\!B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$ is the Frobenius product.

Comment: you end up with something which is neither 1- nor 2-.  For sure $A^TP\neq PA$.

Comment: But notice that ${\rm sym}(A^TP)={\rm sym}(P^TA)={\rm sym}(PA)$, and since the product $x^TPAx$ only uses the symmetric part of $PA$ the products are identical.  In other words, $x^TPAx=x^TA^TPx$

Answer (score 0):

The second is correct - keyword "chain rule". The first is wrong because it differs.

Comment: I dont understand why it is wrong, it is simply a chain rule as well. taking the derivative with respect to x, then multipied by the derivative w.r.t time.